# Should I clean up ivar C++ vector...?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, raii

If a vector is placed in stack, it will be destructed automatically at the end of its automatic variable scope.

What if I have placed a vector in a class?

```
class A
{
    vector<B> bs;  // B is POD struct.
};
```

Should I clean it up manually? If so, how should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That vector `bs` will be destructed  when the enclosing class's destructor (i.e `A`'s destructor) will be called.

```
void f()
{
    {
          A a;
          //working with a;

    }//<--- here a goes out of scope, so it's destructor is called; 
            //so not only a is destructed but also a.bs
}
```

Comment: If destructor is not declared and defined explicitly?

Comment: @Eonil : It doesn't matter as long as you declare `vector<B> bs` where `B` is not a pointer type. Everything is destructed automatically. If however you declare `vector<B*> bs`, and you populate it with elements created with `new`, then you've to write destructor, or some other way to destroy `bs` (i.e all it's elements) manually. The bottomline is : if you use `new`, then you've to use `delete` for the corresponding `new` somewhere in your code. Where exactly depends on your class design, and actual scenario!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each B class that you use in the vector, deletes its own allocated space in the destructor, so when the vector goes out of scope, you wont be left with memory leaks